# How to save variable to NSUserdefaults without fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save some variable to `NSUserDefaults` when tapping on a `UICollectionView` cell, but I get the following error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the code I am using when a cell is tapped.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let text = Globals.sinceLabelArray[indexPath.item]
    userDefaults.setObject(text, forKey: "sinceText")

    let image = String(Globals.imagesArray[indexPath.item])
    userDefaults.setObject(image, forKey: "khoury")

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let daydate = Globals.datesArray[indexPath.item] as String
    userDefaults.setObject(daydate, forKey: "day")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menutohome", sender: nil)
}
```

Here is the view it impacts, and how.

```
let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? NSDate
        let date1 = day
        let date2 = NSDate()
        let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: date1!, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're setting dayDate as String

```
let daydate = Globals.datesArray[indexPath.item] as String // <- String
userDefaults.setObject(daydate, forKey: "day")
```

While when you called it back as NSDate

```
let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? NSDate // <- NSDate
```

UPDATE:

You can save the dateObject as String first into NSUserDefaults. Once you want to use it, then use dateFormatter to make it as NSDate.

Example:

When you call it back from NSUserDefaults

```
        let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? String
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // this format must equal to what it returns from the server

        let dayDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)
        print(dayDate) // your NSDate
```

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure if a variable is nil or not try and use conditional statement before using it for example:

Instead of:

```
let text = Globals.sinceLabelArray[indexPath.item]
userDefaults.setObject(text, forKey: "sinceText")
```

use:

```
if let text = Globals.sinceLabelArray[indexPath.item] {
   userDefaults.setObject(text, forKey: "sinceText")
 } else {
   print("error has happened here")
 }
```